# Add a forward slash between two specific characters with regExp

Tags: javascript, regex, character

I know how to delete/replace elements in a string with regExp. But is it possible to add a character between two specific characters using regExp ?

I'm already using this regExp to match object properties from the value of a user input : `new RegExp("^" + o.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&") + "$", "i");`

This line works just fine for my needs except for adding a forward slash between two specific characters : whenever 'k' is followed by 'm', I need to add a forward slash between them to match the properties of this object :

```
var obj = {
  'km/h': '1.079e+9',
  'km': 0,
  'm/s': '2,998e+8',
  'm': 0
};
```

So if my input value is *'km/h'* or *'kmh'*, both strings should equally match 'km/h' in `obj`. Is it possible to do it using regExp ?

Here is where I'm stuck : https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/p0Lwg85w/1/

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, this seems to be the way to go :

```
var str = "kmh";
var test = str.replace(/m\s?h/i, 'm/h');
console.log(test);
```

Still looking for a more elegant approach or simply a way to implement it in my existing regExp :

```
new RegExp("^" + o.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&") + "$", "i");
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated